# Is it true that every pythagorean triples is of the form $(a^2-b^2)^2+(2ab)^2=(a^2+b^2)$?

Tags: number-theory

For example, the Pythagorean triples $(3,4,5)$ is $(2^2-1^2)^2+(2\times2\times1)^2=(2^2+1^2)^2$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple

Answer (score 6):

*Primitive* Pythagorean triples must have that form.  But there can also be triples with a common factor that prevents the hypoteneuse from being a sum of squares (like a factor of 3 in 9-12-15).

Comment: Why does having common factor greater than 1 implies the hypotenuse is not sum of two squares?

Comment: There could be _a_ common factor that prevents it, specifically one that is itself not a square or the sum of two squares.  There is no claim here that _all_ common factors have this property.

Comment: Hint-If $7|a^2+b^2$ then $7|a$ and $7|b$